# How to show an error in excel file on change of cell value?

Tags: apache, apache-poi, cell

I want to get user confirmation pop up on the excel when changing the cell value from 'no' to 'yes'. how can i do it ?

Comment: How would you do that in pure Excel itself? Figure that one out first, then we can help you with the Apache POI version

Comment: I don't have knowledge on the excel, is that possible to do that ?